# Progressing kettelbells size for home gym

Tags: kettlebell

I'm currently using kettlebell 12 kg for warmup and 20 kg for workout. I'm able to do 40-50 swings with 20kg.

Now I'm considering progressing to heavier one and I'm in doubt should I go for 28 kg or 32 kg (and how many swings should I be able to do before trying heavier one).

Kettlebells that are on the sale where I live progress each 4 kg, and for commercial gym it makes sense to have all weights, but at home, I'm limited both with available place and financial means so I'm looking for reasonable step to progress that would be a compromise between making too large gap and overpaying.

Is a progress from 20 kg to 32 kg too extreme, or I'm still on the safe side (so that I don't risk damage by switching to too heavy weight too soon)? Is there any rule of the thumb for maximal weight difference when switching to heavier kettlebells, similar to 10% rule for weekly running mileage?

Comment: Not an answer, but your question made me think of [this product](https://www.roguecanada.ca/rogue-add-on-change-plate-pair) from Rogue I remember seeing a long time ago. Rogue stuff is always on the pricey side but might be useful. Not sure where you're located.

Comment: @C.Lange I'm aware of the existence of such systems, but they drastically change weight distribution and handling properties (not so relevant for swings, but more for snatches)

Answer (score 2):

> Is a progress from 20 kg to 32 kg too extreme, or I'm still on the
> safe side (so that I don't risk damage by switching to too heavy
> weight too soon)?

Since you can do 40-50 swings with 20kg, which is a lot, that increase seems ok. Focus more on warmup and take it easy until your body gets used to the increased weight.

Heavier weights demand longer rest times, so use a low-rep long rest in the first two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

All things being equal, if you are looking for which weight to progress to with similar reps, I would opt for the 28kg.  Swings require explosiveness and technique, and if you err on too heavy then you could find yourself not able to get enough explosive action out of your hips, and becoming fatigued early on in your high rep workout, leading to bad form and potential injury.  This has happened to me during functional fitness workouts where the instructor suggested too much weight compared to what I was able to execute with kb swings, and he had me step back down.

However, an alternative to consider is getting the 32kg and using both regularly, with the 32kg at way lower reps with an intense focus on technique and the 20kg at higher reps.